# How to get FileDescription with VerQueryValue (getting the example to work)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to get the various attributes of a file as seen in its "Details" tab with the WinAPI function `VerQueryValue`. I have successfully used this function to get the non-string version info with `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`, but have not been able to get the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluea#examples) shown at the bottom of the functions documentation working.

The example isn't actually complete as it leaves out the use of the other related functions and the constructions of some buffers needed to use the function, so I've filled in the blanks the best I can and changed some of the in-between steps to use C++ SL since that's ultimately the language I need to use this in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "sstream"
#include "Windows.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Version.lib")

int ReadOutFileDescriptions(std::wstring filename)
{
    LPBYTE lpBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD  verHandle, verSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(filename.c_str(), &verHandle);

    if (verSize != NULL)
    {
        LPSTR verData = new char[verSize];

        if (GetFileVersionInfo(filename.c_str(), verHandle, verSize, verData))
        {
            UINT cbTranslate;

            // Structure used to store enumerated languages and code pages.
            struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
                WORD wLanguage;
                WORD wCodePage;
            } *lpTranslate;

            // Read the list of languages and code pages.
            VerQueryValue(verData, TEXT("\\VarFileInfo\\Translation"), (LPVOID*)&lpTranslate, &cbTranslate);

            // Read the file description for each language and code page.
            for (ULONGLONG i = 0; i < (cbTranslate / sizeof(struct LANGANDCODEPAGE)); i++)
            {
                std::wostringstream ss; ss << std::setfill(L'0') << std::hex;
                ss << std::setw(4) << lpTranslate[i].wLanguage;
                std::wstring langS = ss.str();
                ss.str(std::wstring());
                ss << std::setw(4) << lpTranslate[i].wCodePage;
                std::wstring codeS = ss.str();
                std::wstring subBlock = L"\\StringFileInfo\\" + langS + codeS + L"\\FileDescription";

                // Retrieve file description for language and code page "i".
                WCHAR descBuffer[50];
                LPVOID lpBuffer = &descBuffer;
                UINT bufferSize;
                VerQueryValue(verData, subBlock.c_str(), &lpBuffer, &bufferSize);
                
                std::cout << bufferSize << '\n' << descBuffer; 
            }
        }

        delete[] verData;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ReadOutFileDescriptions(L"MyFile.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

I only have a little experience with WinAPI and its typedefs and my C is a bit rusty so I'm sure I'm just setting-up/using a buffer incorrectly or the like.

The printed buffer size is correct (the length of `MyFile.exe`'s description + 1 for the null character) so I know the function is getting the right value, but the actually value that gets printed is just a series of hexadecimal character, most likely an address.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT (Answer):**
Thanks to @dxiv I was made aware that I did not fully understand how the "result" argument (lplpBuffer) of VerQueryValue was to be used, both internally and after the function returns.

Changing the end of the loop to the following achieves my desired result:

```
//WCHAR descBuffer[50] Not required, the function doesn't utilize a user made buffer
LPVOID lpBuffer;
UINT bufferSize;

VerQueryValue(verData, subBlock.c_str(), &lpBuffer, &bufferSize); // lpBuffer is reassigned here
std::wstring fileDescription((const TCHAR*)lpBuffer); // Create std::string from C style string (char*) that lpBuffer now points to
std::wcout << bufferSize << '\n' << fileDescription;
```

Comment: std::cout doesn't know beans about a WCHAR[], use std::wcout.  Do favor the debugger.

Comment: Is `lpBuffer` null terminated?

Comment: @Mayur yes, though the length of the string is also placed into the "puLen" (bufferSize here) buffer argument before the call returns

Comment: @oblivioncth but msdn doesn't say anything about null termination. Do you have any source that claims its null terminated?

Comment: It is not mentioned in the docs, but it is null-terminated in practice, at least on my Windows 10 machine with SDK 10.0.18362 (proof: https://i.imgur.com/Lznaziv.png). While generally you shouldn't rely on one implementation, making a change to this behavior would undoubtedly break many applications and is so fundamental I doubt it will be changed. If you still want to be safe, in C++ you can use the constructor std::wstring((const TCHAR*)lpBuffer, *puLen) to specify the str length, or in C you can allocate a buffer that's *puLen+1, strcpy lpBuffer into it, and then do buffer[*puLen+1] = '\0'

Comment: @Mayur not the most stackoverflow formal thing, but I realized I forgot to ping you on my last response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VerQueryValue(verData, subBlock.c_str(), &lpBuffer, &bufferSize);

std::cout << bufferSize << '\n' << descBuffer;
```

Once `VerQueryValue` returns, `lpBuffer` no longer points to `descBuffer`, but to a different buffer assigned inside the call. The returned string is at `(const TCHAR *)lpBuffer` at that point.

Comment: It makes sense to me now why that argument is a void**. I'm used to these functions having you give a pointer to your own buffer for "output", but in this case it constructs the result internally and changes the pointer you provide so that it ultimately points to the start of the result since it is a C style string. I will update the question to employ your correction.

Comment: @oblivioncth Right, the `void **` is a dead giveaway. The other natural question is who owns that pointer and how it gets disposed. Answer to that, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew): "*contains the address of a pointer to the requested version information* ***in the buffer pointed to by pBlock***. *The memory pointed to by lplpBuffer is freed when the associated pBlock memory is freed.*". So, upon return, `lpBuffer` actually points somewhere inside the big `verData` block.